# ASP.NET MVC Unit Testing - Sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, session-variables

Having searched StackOverflow, and Google I think what I'm doing is suppose to be right, however results don't seem to be going well

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LoginAction_Should_Return_View_and_User_Authenticated()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        var mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        mock.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.Session).Returns(mockSession.Object);

        var testData = FakeUserData.CreateTestUsers();
        var repository = new FakeUserRepository(testData);
        var controller = new AccountController(repository);
        controller.ControllerContext = mock.Object;

        // Act
        var result = controller.Login("testuser1", "testuser1");

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("testuser1", controller.HttpContext.Session["Username"]);
        Assert.IsTrue((bool)controller.HttpContext.Session["IsAuthenticated"]);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
    }
```

When I run the test the value of controller.HttpContext.Session["Username"] is null, however I set the value to the username using a Session helper.  Am I doing something completely wrong, or something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to mock a controller's Session :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Mock.Verify to check if underlying code tried to set Session["Username"].

If your code needs to set session variable **and use it** - take a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/06/15/mocking-indexer-setters-with-moq.aspx).

[Quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) is priceless too.